# C++ / CLI: Add item to managed collection

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have created a collection in CLI:

```
List<MyClass>^ list = gcnew List<MyClass>();
```

MyClass is class from c#.

I try to add new item to collection:

```
MyClass^ item = gcnew MyClass();
list->Add(item);
```

In this case I have error: function Add cannot be called with the given argument list.

How to avoid this, I don`t know:(

Please, help!

Answer (score 8):

You need `List<MyClass^>^ list;` (note the additional `^`).

This is because `MyClass` is a reference type, and you can only have references of it (using `^` and created with `gcnew` or via c# code).

```
List<MyClass^>^ list = gcnew List<MyClass>();
MyClass^ item = gcnew MyClass();
list->Add(item);
```